# Survey database with different types of users

Tags: database-design

I'm designing a web app for managing mentor-mentee sessions. Mentees may be presented with different surveys with different types of questions. I would appreciate feedback/criticism on my design so far.

[image: survey model]

Surveys may come in different forms like a normal HTML form or a card sorting activity, or a table that the mentees have to fill.

Answers to questions may be in a yes/no, list form, a drawing, or plain text. Similarly, questions may be plain text, tables, fill in the blank etc. I created a content field for both question and answer in which I plan to store question/answer data in xml format, so if it's a table I can retrieve individual columns easily in the app logic. Is this a good idea?

I also created a separate logTimes table to track user logins and whether it was successful or not. A login may be from either a volunteer (mentor or supervisor) or a mentee, so one of idVolunteer or idMentee in this table will always be null. What do you think?